# HTML to PDF converter for Angular 6

Tags: angular6, jspdf, html2pdf

What are some of the best HTML to PDF converter for Angular 6? I have tried to use

> jspdf

along with

> html2canvas

but it totally and massively ruins the design of the HTML.

Please check my code below -

```
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'; 

html2canvas(document.getElementById('documentToPrint')).then(canvas => {
      var imgWidth = 208;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      var position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

            const page = await browser.newPage();



            await page.setContent(`<html>`+req.body.inputValue['htmlContent']+`</html>`);//'<html><body>'+req.body.html+'</body></html>
            await page.emulateMedia('screen');


            filepath = path.join(__dirname,'../../uploads/pdf_output') +'/'+ req.body.inputValue['appNo'] + '/' + 'application-0.pdf';

            console.log("file name with path "+filepath);
            await page.pdf({


                printBackground: true,
                path: filepath

            });

            await browser.close();
```